# prove that $(E_{p^n},*)$ is cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, ring-theory

if $p \in$ $\mathbb{N}$ is a prime integer, how can i prove that $E_{p^n}$ the group of invertible elements of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^n\mathbb{Z}}$   is a cyclic group.

Comment: It suffies to prove that each primepower has a primitive root, and that will be your candidate as the generater of the group